# Why my azure function is not logging errors in Application Insights?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

My functions are working fine, but when I try to handle errors and log them using the "context.error", they are not being sent to Applications Insights, only the requests are being registered. Shouldn't the "context.error" log the error straight to App Insights? Am I missing something?

Here's my Error Handler function:

```
module.exports = function handleError(context, error) {
  context.error(error);

  let isInternalError = error.statusCode === 500 || error.code === 500 || typeof error.code !== "number";
  let status = isInternalError ? 500 : error.statusCode || error.code || 500;
  let errorMessage = error.message;
  let errorsList = [];
  
  if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
    isInternalError = false;
    status = 400;
    errorsList = Object.keys(error.errors).map(key => error.errors[key].message);
    errorMessage = "Validation Error";
  }

  return {
    status,
    jsonBody: {
      errorMessage: isInternalError ? 'Internal Server Error' : errorMessage,
      errorsList,
      errorStack: process.env.ENVIRONMENT !== "prod" ? error.stack : undefined
    }
  };
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the "context.error" log the error straight to App Insights?

You need to initialize telemetry client before calling  **`context.error`** method. You can refer to this [Ms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs#telemetryclient-api) for info.

In order to log the errors in Application Insights, I have added the following lines of code in your existing code.

```
const  appInsights  =  require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup(process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING).start();
module.exports  =  function  handleError(context) {
appInsights.defaultClient.trackException({ exception:  error });
context.error(error);
```

**`Output`**:

[image]

*I can see the logs in application insights as well*

[image]

Comment: I never thought of initialising it as I thought it would automatically register the error, the same way it registers the requests. Thank you! I just have another problem... "error" object that I'm sending in the "exception" to app insights doesn't have the same stack as the one it's been printed by the "context.error". The one printed in the console has the exact file and line the error was thrown, but the one in the app insights doesn't, and it's the exact same error object. Any ideas?